# Spring Batch file reader doesn't read all the rows in a file

Tags: java, spring-batch, filereader

I am using Spring Batch to process the uploaded file. When i try to read the file which is having 30K records, it only read 18k rows and processed. It didn't consider remaining records. These are the bean declared on my config.

```js
<job id="JobSeq1" restartable="true" parent="ParentJob">
  <step id="DelegateTask" next = "FileParser" >
   <tasklet ref = "JobTask">
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="PromotionListener" />
    </listeners>
   </tasklet> 
  </step>
  
  <step id="FileParser" next = "FileStaggingProcessor" >
   <tasklet ref = "FileParserTask">
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="PromotionListener" />
    </listeners>
   </tasklet> 
  </step>
  
  <step id="FileStaggingProcessor">
   <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="FileReader" writer="FileWriter"
     commit-interval="100" skip-limit="100">
      <skippable-exception-classes>
       <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
      </skippable-exception-classes> 
    </chunk>
   </tasklet>
  </step>
  </job>
  
  <beans:bean id="FileReader"
  class="org.com.myProj.FileReader"> 
   <beans:property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/> 
   <beans:property name="lineMapper">
   <beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
   
    <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
     <beans:bean
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
      <beans:property name="delimiter" value="," /> 
     </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="myMapper">
    </beans:property>
   </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="saveState" value="true"></beans:property>    
 </beans:bean>
```

And the reader looks like

```js
public class FileReader extends FlatFileItemReader<CombMappingVO> implements 
StepExecutionListener{

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) throws 
StepListenerFailedException{
if(!inputFilePath.isEmpty() && !ObjectValidator.isObjectNull(inputFilePath))
    {
 String csvInputFilePath = new Helper().convert2CSV(inputFilePath);
 super.setResource(new FileSystemResource(csvInputFilePath));
 }
 }
}
```

I use a mapper to load the file data to a temp table and i could see exactly 18K records. Is there a way to identify where the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried ItemReaderListener yet? It supports beforeRead, afterRead, and onError

Comment: I wouldn't recommend extending the `FlatFileItemReader` like you have.  I'd recommend using a `FactoryBean` for the resource (how I describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407408/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-resources-reference-from-another-class/48407722#48407722).  After the 18k records, does the reader return null or is there an exception or ?